# How to efficiently find the probability of a distance metric conditional on both indices equaling 1

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

### The Problem

I am attempting to solve a challenge on HackerRank that asks the following: Given a string $S$ of length $N$ that consists of only zeros and ones, if two indices, $i$ and $j$ are chosen at random between $1$ and $N$, both inclusive, what is the probability that $S[i]=1$ and $S[j]=1$ and $|i - j| \leq K$? [Source](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-probability/copy-from/33986567)

### My Solution

Here is the algorithm that I'm trying written in Python:

```
# N is the length of the string, and K is the threshold
N, K = [int(d) for d in str(raw_input()).split(" ")]
# S is the string
S = str(raw_input())
# Each element can be paired with itself and every other, so there are N^2 possible combinations of two indices
d = N**2
# For the same reason, we can just count the number of elements that are a 1 and square that for the numerator
n = S.count("1")**2
# Probability of Event A - S[i] = 1 and S[j] = 1
p_a = float(n)/float(d)
# Get the index of all 1s
idx = [i for i,ltr in enumerate(S) if ltr == "1"]
tpls = []
# Loop through those indices to create the tuples
for i in idx:
    for j in idx:
        tpls.append((i, j))
# Calculate |i - j|
vals = [abs(tpl[0] - tpl[1]) for tpl in tpls]
# Find all differences that meet criteria
thresh = [abs(tpl[0] - tpl[1]) for tpl in tpls if abs(tpl[0] - tpl[1]) <= K]
d = len(vals)
n = len(thresh)
# Probability of Event B: |i - j| <= K
p_b = float(n)/float(d)
answer = p_a * p_b
print answer
```

### The Issue

My solution passes the practice test case, which tells me I have one right approach, but on the actual test cases I get a runtime error, meaning the algorithm is taking too long.

### My Question

Given the fact that I get the right answer on the test case, but time out on more complex test cases, what is a more efficient approach to this problem? I'm looking to understand the mathematics of the approach, and not the programmatic solution, which is why I'm posting here instead of Stack Overflow.